# Proper way to use a Rack middleware from a gem in a Rails project with Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, rack, middleware

I've got a Rails project that's setup using Bundler. One of my bundled gems provides a Rack middleware that I'd like to use in my Rails app (but only in the 'production' Rails environment).

If I just put something like this in `config/environments/production.rb`, I get an unknown constant error:

```
config.middleware.use ::Rack::MyMiddleware
```

... presumably because `Bundler.require` has not yet been called at this point, and none of my bundled gems are available.

I have found a few ways of working around this, but none seem great, and I'm wondering if there's a more standard solution that I'm missing:

1. Explicitly `require 'my_middleware_gem'` in `config/environments/production.rb`
2. Wrap the `config.middleware.use` call in an `after_initialize` block, ensuring that Bundler has a chance to do its thing before I try to reference the constant.
3. Use a string (`"::Rack::MyMiddleware"`) instead of the bare class constant. This doesn't seem to work with Unicorn for some reason, but does work with some other servers (with Unicorn it ends up trying to call `"::Rack::MyMiddleware".new`, which of course fails).

Am I missing some better approach? At what point in the initialization process is it expected that bundled gems should be available?

Comment: Bundled gems should be available in your environments - `Bundle.require` is called just after `require 'rails/all'`. What’s the name of the gem, and is that the same as the name as the file to be required? Do you need something like `gem 'my_middleware_gem', :require => 'rack/my_middleware`' in your `Gemfile`? See: http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm on Rails 2.3.8 still (I know, I know) with the setup described at http://gembundler.com/rails23.html. I suspect that the behavior regarding when Bundler.require is called may be different for Rails 2. Regarding your suggestion, though - the name of the gem matches up with the require statement necessary to use it, and adding the `:require` option in my Gemfile seems to have no effect on this particular behavior.

Comment: I was wrong - the `Gemfile` isn’t loaded until _after_ the environment, in Rails 2 and 3. It looks like Rails’ autoloading of constants _does_ work though, and sometimes that is enough, but not in this case it seems.

Comment: I think using the `after_initialize` block is the right way in this case.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up going with. Thanks! Regarding the unicorn issue alluded to in the original question, turns out I was hitting this problem: http://davidvollbracht.com/blog/headachenewunicorn-capistrano-bundler-usr2

Comment: @matt or grumbler - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

[matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214790/matt) suggested:

> I think using the `after_initialize` block is the right way in this case.

[grumbler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187529/grumbler) confirmed:

> Yeah, that's what I ended up going with. Thanks! Regarding the unicorn issue alluded to in the original question, turns out I was hitting this problem: http://davidvollbracht.com/blog/headachenewunicorn-capistrano-bundler-usr2